# autorun.inf file not working on pc

Tags: autorun, dvd, dvd-burning

I created an autorun.inf file for my dvd so that it would display a splash page (just an image), then go directly to and open a pdf. As well as set the icon for the drive. However the icon didn't change, and neither the splash page or pdf opened or displayed upon inserting the disc.

My code in the autorun.info file is as follows

```
[AutoRun]
OPEN=winopen \start_here.pdf filename splash.jpg
ICON=icon.ico
```

The .inf file is sitting in the same folder as the start_here.pdf, the splash.jpg and the icon.ico.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open statement does not open the associated file, but only executable and html-files. To launch the associated files by their extensions, you must use "ShellExecute" statement.

The shellexecute command is more flexible than the open command and will allow you to open nearly any file on a PC in its native application, so can be used for PDFs, Word files, web pages and movies where the open command would not work.

```
[AutoRun]
shellexecute=myfile.pdf
```